# Show that the $G_f$ of $f$ is connected on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Tags: continuity, connectedness

Let $f: [a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Define the graph of $f$ as $G_f:= \{(x, f (x)) \in \mathbb{R}^2: x \in [a,b]\}$. Show that the $G_f$ of $f$ is connected on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Let's define $F: [a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ such as $F(x):= (x, f(x)); \forall x \in [a,b]$.

I already proof that $F$ is continuous in $[a, b]$.

How [a,b] is compact on $\mathbb{R}$, I know that the $F([a,b])=G_f$ is compact.

Comment: Replace the words *how* and *compact* to *since* and *connected*, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $g: [a,b] \to G_f$ given by $g(x) = (x, f(x)).$ Show that $g$ is continuous, then assume $A \cup B = G_f$ for non-empty open sets $A, B.$ Do you see what to do next?

Comment: Yes, please. Can you show me what did you do next?

Comment: @Dunnia $[a,b]$ is connected, now use proof by contradiction.